# Loading jquery script from CDN works, but loading same script from IIS yields illegal character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iis, newline

In my static webpage loaded from IIS (v8.5.9600), I include jquery with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And when loading the page in the firefox browser I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character [Learn More] jquery.min.js:1
```

If I load it from the CDN, everything is fine, my code runs and I get no errors (my code is in the html page and thus not included from another script).

```
<script type=“text/javascript” src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
```

I downloaded the file from the CDN and copied it directly into IIS, but when it loads I still get the error in Firefox about an illegal character.

Both of the files from the CDN and IIS load up, so that is not the issue, but I did notice that when the file is loaded from the CDN it looks like this:

[image: image of browser filled with minified jquery]

But when I load it from IIS (v8.5) it looks like this:

[image: image of browser with minified straight line of jquery]

P.S. I tried loading a simple script from IIS (not from the CDN) as well and I get the same error.  Is it something to do with IIS's settings?

Comment: `type=\`"text/javascript\`"`  What's with the weird quotes?

Comment: Chances are, the path you're using to request the script file isn't correct and IIS is returning the 404 HTML page

Comment: @Phil That’s cause a powershell script is writing out the page, escaping the double quotes , I’ll fix it.

Comment: @leeand00 could you please share the browser network tab snapshot which shows the script file name. please make sure it is the same as you set anything is not missing there. from src=`"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js`" try to remove the single quote. try to use another browser.add charset="utf-8" in script tag.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Thank you!  That was the issue.  Your `charset="utf-8"` attribute did the trick.  I guess that tells the browser to request the file in `uft-8` format, it's great too because I didn't have to modify the configuration of IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the browser network tab snapshot which shows the script file name and make sure it loads up on its own from the URL you specfied in the `src` attribute of your `<script>` tag.

Your Javascript `<script>` include tags need to have the `charset="utf-8"` attribute so that the browser requests the script from the server in the utf-8 encoding.